# Solving a cubic equation

Tags: functions, problem-solving, cubics

Solve $y=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$

I need $x$ in terms of $y$ . I do not need the roots of the cubic equation . I need to express  $x$ in terms of $y, x>0$

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: But you *do* need the roots of the cubic equation $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d-y = 0$! (exclamation, not factorial)

Comment: See [cubic formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula_for_roots).

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $x=z- \frac{b}{3a}$ and use the [Cardano formula](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Cardano_formula).